# Como pegar apenas uma célula de um arquivo CSV com PHP?

Tags: php, microsoft-excel, phpexcel

Como faço para pegar apenas uma linha de uma coluna específica? No código abaixo ele me mostra todas as linhas e todas as colunas que tem no arquivo CSV. Quero apenas uma célula específica.

**Exemplo:** 
Coluna B - Carros
Linha 2 - Fox
Célula da linha e da coluna - B2

Quero pegar apenas essa célula *B2* e imprimi-la na tela.

```
<?php
// activar Error reporting
error_reporting(E_ALL);

// carregar a classe PHPExcel
require_once 'Classes/PHPExcel.php';

// iniciar o objecto para leitura
$objReader = new PHPExcel_Reader_CSV();$objReader->setInputEncoding('CP1252');
$objReader->setDelimiter(';');
$objReader->setEnclosure('');
$objReader->setSheetIndex(0);
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load("itens.csv");

//Pegando o total de colunas
$colunas       = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getHighestColumn();
$total_colunas = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($colunas);

//Pegando o total de linhas
$total_linhas = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getHighestRow();

echo "<table border='1'>";
// navegar na linha
for($linha=1; $linha<= $total_linhas; $linha++){
    echo "<tr>";
    // navegar nas colunas da respactiva linha
    for($coluna=1; $coluna<= $total_colunas -1; $coluna++){
        if($linha==1){
        // escreve o cabeçalho da tabela
            echo "<th>".utf8_decode($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCellByColumnAndRow($coluna, $linha)->getValue())."</th>";
        }else{
        // escreve os dados da tabela
            echo "<td>".utf8_decode($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCellByColumnAndRow($coluna, $linha)->getValue())."</td>";
        }
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: No caso, você apenas fez o `for` para gerar a tabela a partir do CSV, correto? Tem como você descrever como tentou fazer para obter somente essa célula? Pode ser só uma descrição da lógica, caso não saiba qual é o código.

Comment: Acho que não entendi. Eu não estou pegando apenas uma célula, eu peguei tudo que estava no arquivo CSV. Eu quero pegar apenas 1 célula. que no meu arquivo ela se chama AI2.

Comment: Foi o que eu disse. O seu código na pergunta está pegando todo o conteúdo e gerando uma tabela HTML, mas não possui nenhuma tentativa de encontrar apenas a célula desejada. Você chegou a tentar fazer algo nesse sentido?

Comment: Ah sim. Não, eu não sei como faz isso. Por isso vim aqui perguntar, eu não sei fazer que ele gere apenas uma célula, apenas sei gerar a tabela toda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Desconstrua o CSV pegando o índice da coluna pela primeira linha e buscando o valor pela linha especificada, por exemplo, para a tabela:

```
1 | a  | b  | c  |
2 | AA | BB | CC |
3 | XX | YY | ZZ |
```

Queremos o valor da célula B2, então:

```
$csv = "a,b,c\nAA,BB,CC\nXX,YY,ZZ";
$celula = array( 'b','2' );

// Crie um array com as linhas
$linhas = explode( "\n", $csv ); // array( 'a,b,c', 'AA,BB,CC', 'XX,YY,ZZ' );

// Crie um array com as colunas da primeira linha
$header = explode( ',', $linhas[0] ); // array( 'a', 'b, 'c' );

// Crie um array com as colunas da linha que vc quer buscar
$colunas_linha = explode( ',', $linhas[ $celula[1]-1 ] ); // array( 'AA', 'BB, 'CC' );

// Pegue o índice da coluna que você quer buscar pelo nome
$indice_coluna = array_search( $celula[0], $header, true ); // 1

// Depois pegue o valor da célula buscando o índice no array da coluna
echo $colunas_linha[$indice_coluna]; // 'BB'
```

ps.: no exemplo a numeração não faz parte da tabela (como é comum em CSV), incluí somente pra ficar mais clara a visualização

[**Exemplo funcional**](https://eval.in/825245)